# r summarize_if with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, mode, reduction, summarize

I'm trying to reduce a df of observations to a single observation (single line).
I would like to summarize_if is numeric with the mean and if is string or factor with the mode. The code below doesn't work, but I hope it gives the idea.
Thanks!

```
#data frame
num <- c(1:7)
str <- c("toy","control","play",NA,"give","toy","toy")
df_finale <- data.frame(num,str)

#mode function
Mode <- function(x) {
        ux <- unique(x)
        ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

#df reduction
df_finale <- df_finale %>%
                    summarize_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
                    summarize_else_if(!is.numeric, Mode)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility could be:

```
df_finale %>%
 summarise_all(~ if(is.numeric(.)) mean(., na.rm = TRUE) else Mode(.))

  num str
1   4 toy
```

Or an option since `dplyr 1.0.0`:

```
df_finale %>%
 summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(is.numeric(.)) mean(., na.rm = TRUE) else Mode(.)))
```

Comment: Great! Where can I place na.rm = TRUE in the mean formula?

Comment: You can simply use `mean(., na.rm = TRUE)` :)

Comment: And please note, that the mode function you've chosen will only return the first mode is there are more than one, where first means that it is the first string encountered

Answer (score 1):

We could use `mutate_if` with `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_finale %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
     mutate_if(negate(is.numeric), Mode) %>%
     distinct
#   num str
#1   4 toy
```

---

Or with `across/summarise` from the new version of `dplyr`

```
i1 <- df_finale %>% 
           summarise_all(is.numeric) %>%
           flatten_lgl

df_finale %>% 
     summarise(across(names(.)[i1], ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE)), 
               across(names(.)[!i1], Mode))
```